# how to connect input and function module in main module and can we return list from a function?

Tags: python, list

I have three modules: GetInput, Main and Converter. In the GetInput file there are all the inputs values and excel data in the form of list. In the Converter file I am using those input values from Getinput file and in the main file I am connecting both these files here. I am doing this so that my code can look more organized. 
GetInput.py:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time

def getInputs():
    df = pd.read_excel('input.xlsx')
    actual = df['actual'].values.tolist()
    schedule = df['schedule'].values.tolist()
    freq = df['frequency'].values.tolist()
    ACP = df['acp'].values.tolist()


    modelInput = {
        'actual': actual, 'schedule': schedule, 'freq': freq, 'ACP': ACP,'df' : df
    }
    return modelInput
```

Converter.py

```
import pandas as pd
def fun(modelInput):
    underdraw = []
    overdraw = []
    for i,j, in zip(schedule, actual):
        dev = j - i
        if dev < 0:
            underdraw.append(dev)
        else:
            underdraw.append(0)

        if dev > 0:
            overdraw.append(dev)
        else:
            overdraw.append(0)

    df['underdraw'] = pd.Series(underdraw)
    df['overdraw'] = pd.Series(overdraw)
    df.to_excel('mainfile.xlsx')
```

Main.py

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from convert import *
from GetInputs import *

def fun1():
    inpu = getInputs()
    con = fun(inpu)
fun1()
```

This whole program works when I run it in a single module but it throw errors when I try divide my code into separate modules. Basically it throw error in `GetInput.py` and in `Converter.py` (df is not defined) file. I know its a very basic thing but I don't know how to make it work. There is no desired output for this program, I am already getting an output when I run it in a single file. I just want to divide my code in this format as I mentioned above: GetIput File, Converter File and Main File.

Answer (score 0):

Keep all the files in same directory or else mention the file paths at the top of main code using `os` module.

You have misspelled the following in the main code:

```
from convert import *
from GetInputs import *
```

It should be:

```
from Converter import *
from GetInput import *
```

I have tested this using the following:

**MainModule.py**

```
from Converter import *
from GetInputs import *

def fun1():
    inpu = getInputs()
    con = fun(inpu)
fun1()
```

**Converter.py**

```
import pandas as pd
def fun(modelInput):
    print("HIE" + modelInput)
```

**GetInputs.py**

```
def getInputs():
    return "modelInput"
```

Comment: i want return a dictionary from GetInput file and use it in converter file

Comment: Check this in main file.

```from Converter import *
from GetInput import *```

Comment: @nipunvats You habe misspelled import files names in main.py